Choosing number of classes in LCA
I'm an undergrad student, a little confused about goodness of fit tests. I'm trying to choose the appropriate number of classes for a latent class analysis using  poLCA package in R. My data has 89 observed binary variables and I'm comparing goodness of fit statistics to determine the correct number of classes.
The AIC and BIC values decrease with increase in number of classes but they plateau after the 4th class, the log likelihood also plateau after the 4th class as well. Having said that, the BIC and AIC values do keep decreasing even after 10 classes although by a small margin.
Am I mistaken to think 4 classes is appropriate or should I be doing something else entirely?
I appreciate any reading material also, always looking to learn. Thank you.
> aic_values
 [1] 509311.8 456245.0 436084.9 426650.1 422403.6 417608.8 413242.8 411011.4 408163.3 406278.5 404276.3
> bic_values
 [1] 510443.8 457946.6 438356.2 429491.0 425814.1 421588.9 417792.5 416130.7 413852.2 412537.0 411104.5
> log_lik
 [1] -254498.9 -227886.5 -217727.5 -212931.0 -210728.8 -208252.4 -205990.4 -204795.7 -203292.6 -202271.2 -201191.2




